# Promise's .then() does not accept function assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, promise

```
Promise.resolve(123)
    .then(String)
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
    })
```

works fine here.

However, if I assign the function to a variable, and pass to the `Promise's .then()`. The function simply ignores my callback.

For example,

```
Promise.resolve(123)
    .then(String)
    .then(myFunc)

var myFunc = (data)=>{
    console.log(data)
}
```

It does not print anything. The only difference is that the function is assigned to a variable and then pass to the .then(), instead of passing directly. But as far as I know, there should be no difference. Why is that?

(btw, I tried the pre-ES6 traditional function syntax as well and it made no difference)

Comment: Order matters. `var myFunc = ....` assigns the function to `myFunc` when `Promise` chain was already constructed using `myFunc` being `undefined`.

Comment: hoisting ... try moving var myFunc above the other code - or, declaring myFunc using `function myFunc` - the whole function def is hoisted `I tried the pre-ES6 traditional function syntax as well and it made no difference` I bet you did `var x = function()` rather than `function x()`

Answer (score 6):

As indicated in the comments, this isn't a problem with using functions that are assigned to a variable. It's a problem with using variables that don't have a value yet.

> The only difference is that the function is assigned to a variable and then pass to the .then(), instead of passing directly.

No, actually, it's passed to `.then()` *and then* assigned to a variable. There's a big difference.

In this example, `myFunc` is `undefined` when you are using it:

```js
Promise.resolve(123)
  .then(String)
  .then(myFunc)

console.log('myFunc is', myFunc);

var myFunc = (data) => {
  console.log(data)
}
```

Solution: ensure that `myFunc` has a value *before* you use it:

```js
var myFunc = (data) => {
  console.log(data)
}

Promise.resolve(123)
  .then(String)
  .then(myFunc)

console.log('myFunc is', myFunc);
```

Comment: Or better yet use `function myFunc() {}` so you don't have to worry about order.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that would definitely work, but it seems that it's in vogue today to use `const` with an arrow function rather than use a function declaration. `const myFunc = (data) => console.log(data);`. I think there's something to be said for defining things before you use them anyway.

Comment: "In vogue".  No, just an over reaction to a new toy.  Function hoisting was put into the language for a very good reason.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's pretty much what "in vogue" means. :) I don't know what Eich's actual motivations were for including function hoisting, but I'm guessing it had a lot to do with stopping people from cutting themselves back when JS was  in its early days. Surely, it's nice to have the option to hoist functions, but a lot of decent languages (LISP, F#) get by just fine without any mechanism resembling function hoisting.

Comment: Without function hoisting, you're left with wasting time trying to find the right order of function declaration that makes the compiler/interpreter happy, particular in older code that you didn't write that you're trying to make modifications to.  Frankly that time is nearly always just wasted - no real benefit.  Languages like C let you predefine the function signature in a pre-included header to solve this.  The only "feature" `const fn = function() {}` really adds is to prevent redeclaration or reassignment of the function name.  But module development generally solves that issue anyway.